# automated conversion of coordinates to country, city and street location using google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a sort of gprs device fitted to a car that returns the location coordinates of a car.

I am trying to link this device with google maps. So that when you query for the cars location, using the coordinates returned by the device and using google maps it is able to give you the country, city, street position of the car.

Is there a service that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 7):

It's called reverse geocoding.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding